# Correct scope for spring beans on Rest Service

Tags: spring, rest, resteasy

I'm creating a REST service using RestEasy and Spring 4.

The service is basically an endpoint for a complex batch process. So clients call the service passing a bunch of parameters and then the processing is triggered.

As there are many parameters that are initially passed to the service, and those parameters are used pretty much everywhere in the system, I've chosen to create a 'helper' bean that will hold the parameters, then every other bean can autowire the 'parameter bean' and use it.

example:

the url called by the client would be: `http://localhost/rest/service/execute?processType=A&initialDate=20141220&finalDate=20141231......`

The REST Service endpoint would be something like:

```
@Path("/service")
public class RESTService {  
    @Autowired
    private RequestParams params;

    @Autowired
    private ProcessOrchestrator orchestrator;

    @POST
    @Path("/execute")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response executa(
            @NotNull @QueryParam("processType") String processType,
            @NotNull @QueryParam("initialDate") String initialDate,
            @NotNull @QueryParam("finalDate") String finalDate,
            ...
            ) {

        params.setProcessType(processType);
        params.setInitialDate(initialDate);
        params.setFinalDate(finalDate);

        orchestrator.triggerBatchProcess();        

    }
}
```

The RequestParams bean will only hold the parameters values:

```
@Component
public class RESTService {  
    private String processType;
    private String initialDate;
    private String finalDate;
    ...
    // getters and setters
}
```

And the other beans would @Autowire the params bean and use its parameters:

```
@Component
public class DataProcessor {    
     @Autowire
     private RequestParams params;
     //...
}

@Component
public class DataConverter {    
     @Autowire
     private RequestParams params;
     //...
}

@Component
public class FileWritter {  
     @Autowire
     private RequestParams params;
     //...
}
```

The design looks correct, right? Now, my concern is: how do I make sure that a new `RequestParams` instance is created every time the service is called? Do I need to declare a scope ("request" for instance) for all my beans?

Comment: Currently the design isn't correct, but that is related to your question. The `RequestParams` should be request scoped, although why do you want to autowire everything? What is wrong with creating a new instance and pass it as a method parameter?

Comment: `RequestParams` holds values that are used pretty much everywhere in the system. I would have to pass it as a param to dozens of methods. Also, in the future, I might need to use a certain request param value in a method that didn't need to use it before. In that case I would need to change the method signature, interfaces, etc.

Comment: Change should be hard as that makes you think about your design. Making something a request scoped bean just for the purpose of passing params around for me feels a bit non OO and introduces additional complexity in your application. But that is imho.

Comment: ok @M.Deinum thanks for your input. I'm sticking with the parameters bean. I've run some tests using the `request` scope and it works great.